# OpenGL: How to set z co-ordinate of vertex to positive quantity?

Tags: vb.net, opengl, graphics, 3d, opentk

I'm just starting to learn opengl so I may not know all things. Using OpenTK with VB.net.

I have this code:

```
    Dim pm As Matrix4 = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(1.57, 16 / 9, 0.1, 100)
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection)
    GL.LoadMatrix(pm)
    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Triangles)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, -1) : GL.Color4(1.0!, 0!, 0!, 1.0!)
    GL.Vertex3(1, 0, -1) : GL.Color4(0.0!, 1.0!, 0!, 1.0!)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 1, -1) : GL.Color4(0.0!, 0.0!, 1.0!, 1.0!)
    GL.End()
```

This correctly draws the triangle.

But when I change the z co-ordinate to +ve, they disappear. Like when `GL.Vertex3(0, 0, +1)`, that vertex disappears. When all 3 vertices' z coords are +ve then nothing is visible.
I thought that this was because of some matrix stuff so I added a translation to the 'pm' matrix defined above:

```
        Matrix4.CreateTranslation(0, 0, +1.0!, pm)
```

Still nothing happens.

But when all are -ve then all is good:

```
GL.Vertex3(0, 0, -10) : GL.Color4(1.0!, 0!, 0!, 1.0!)
GL.Vertex3(1, 0, -10) : GL.Color4(0.0!, 1.0!, 0!, 1.0!)
GL.Vertex3(0, 1, -10) : GL.Color4(0.0!, 0.0!, 1.0!, 1.0!)
```

Note: I've followed [this](http://genericgamedev.com/tutorials/opengl-in-csharp-an-object-oriented-introduction-to-opentk/) guide. His code seems to have the same problem though no one addressed it. [His code](https://github.com/amulware/genericgamedev-opentk-intro)

Can someone explain this stuff to me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL one usually assumes that the camera is looking in -z direction (it's a convention, not a limit). Due to this, projection matrices are usually constructed in a way that they map the interval between [-nearPlane, -farPlane] to the visible depth region.

If you want to look in positive z, then you have to add a additional viewing matrix that rotates the camera by 180° around the y-axis (Or one that simply mirrors the z-axis but then the winding order changes).